# Get the Name of the Maximum age in 2 lists in C#

Tags: c#, list

I am relatively new to C#.

I am trying to find the name of the maximum age from a list of names and ages.
I don't know which names or which ages are given in advance unlike the example below.

The names and ages are created from two lists below.

```
List<string> name = new List<string>();
List<double> age = new List<double>();
```

I know how to find the maximum age with the Max() method but how do I get the corresponding name?
With the example below is there a way to create new objects from a list?

```
/// This class implements IComparable to be able to  
/// compare one Pet to another Pet. 
/// </summary> 
class Pet : IComparable<Pet>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Compares this Pet to another Pet by  
    /// summing each Pet's age and name length. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="other">The Pet to compare this Pet to.</param>
    /// <returns>-1 if this Pet is 'less' than the other Pet,  
    /// 0 if they are equal, 
    /// or 1 if this Pet is 'greater' than the other Pet.</returns> 
    int IComparable<Pet>.CompareTo(Pet other)
    {
        int sumOther = other.Age + other.Name.Length;
        int sumThis = this.Age + this.Name.Length;

        if (sumOther > sumThis)
            return -1;
        else if (sumOther == sumThis)
            return 0;
        else 
            return 1;
    }
}

public static void MaxEx3()
{
    Pet[] pets = { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                   new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
                   new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } };

    Pet max = pets.Max();

    Console.WriteLine(
        "The 'maximum' animal is {0}.",
        max.Name);
}

/*
 This code produces the following output:

 The 'maximum' animal is Barley.
*/
```

Comment: I don't think that Max() as used in your example would automagically determine which child member has the highest 'Age' property.  Additionally, your Compare implementation appears to be adding the length of the Pet.Name string to the age before comparison (e.g. Pet { Name='Bob', Age=4 } is equal to Pet { Name = 'NotBob', Age='1'}.  Perhaps fix this method to evaluate the properties separately as well?

Comment: The code is just an example I thought was close. List name = new List(); List age = new List(); are where my names and ages are. I need to get the name from the max age in two lists...  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution could be modify the `CompareTo()` method with:

```
int IComparable<Pet>.CompareTo(Pet pet)
{
    return this.Age.CompareTo( pet.Age );
}
```

Then:

```
var olderPet = pets.Max(); 
Console.WriteLine(olderPet.Name);
```

**EDIT 1:**

> How do I get the Name and Age from two lists though? List name = new
>   List(); List age = new List(); is where I have the info.

If I understood you need to create another list of Pets from two list given. So
you have to add this to `Pet` class:

```
public Pet(string Name, int Age){
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Age = Age;
}
```

And then do this to create the list of Pets from the two lists:

```
List<Pet> listPets = new List<Pet>();
for(int i = 0; i < listNames.Count; i++){
    listPets.Add(new Pet(name[i], age[i]));
}
```

Remember that the two lists must have the same length else this code will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

**EDIT 2:**

> However when I put it all together I get output of "Pet.Pet". How can
>   I paste the code to show?

If you want to print all the content of the new list you can do:

```
foreach(Pet pet in listPets)
  Console.WriteLine("Name: " + pet.Name + "," + "Age: " + pet.Age.ToString());
```

Or you can add this to your pet class:

```
public override string ToString(){
   return "Name: " + Name + "," + "Age: " + Age.ToString();
}
```

And then use this code to print all the content of the list:

```
foreach(Pet pet in listPets)
  Console.WriteLine(pet.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I get the Name and Age from two lists though? List name = new List(); List age = new List(); is where I have the info. That code is an example that already has the names and ages in the method... ?

Comment: Thanks for your help Fuex. However when I put it all together I get output of "Pet.Pet". How can I paste the code to show? I only have 500 characters...

Comment: This worked. So I know the listPets.Add(new Pet(Name[i], Age[i])); from before is working. However, I'm still stumped. Why is var olderPet = listPets.Max(); returning "Pet.Pet". It compiles okay so I don't understand ???

Comment: Becuase when you write `Console.WriteLine(olderPet)` you print the class name because `olderPet` is of type `Pet` and it isn't a string. Infact it doesn't return the property `Name`. So you have to use `Console.WriteLine(olderPet.Name);`. Did you understand?

Comment: Yes thats what I put and it works now. Thanks for your help, I am only getting used to using objects as types. ;)

Comment: Glad to help you. Can you accept/mark my answer? If you don't know how to do [click here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Fuex - perhaps you can help again. I can't use the :IComparable<Pet> because I am already inheriting another class. Is there a way I can create a regular method to compare?

Comment: This is very vague can you post your code on [pastebin.com](http://www.pastebin.com)?

Comment: Ok, I see. I used the one where it didn't override the operators. So we create an Pet object max, set it to null similar to how we deal with other types (int, double etc) then compare the age of pet vs the age of max. I get it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

```
var pet = pets.OrderByDescending(p => p.Age).First();    

var name = pets.OrderByDescending(p => p.Age).First().Name;
```

you can also use [morelinq's MaxBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c)

```
var name = pets.MaxBy(p=>p.Age).Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused.  You ask "how do I get the corresponding name?" and your code return correct answer.  Then you ask "Is there a way to create new objects from a list?"  The answer is yes, but what exactly do you want to archieve by doing that?

Your CompareTo-method is not correct if you want to find the oldest pet.
It should look like this:

```
public int IComparable<Pet>.CompareTo(Pet other)
{
    return this.Age - other.Age;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, that Compare method gets the proper age. However my problem is getting the names and ages to compare. That is, they are not defined in the MaxEx3() method as the example shows. My name and ages are defined in two lists. List name = new List(); List age = new List(); How can I get them into a method to compare? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate both lists using Zip:

```
var pets = names.Zip(ages, (n, a) => new Pet { Name = n, Age = a });
```

Then you can use Max to get the maximum according to your comparison function:

```
var maxPet = pers.Max();
```